# how to access the class attribute of a div tag inside a td using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have rendered the below table

```
   <table id="layout" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
           <td>
             <div style="position: static;" class="type_normal type_common" title="33">33</div>
           </td>
           <td>
             <div style="position: static;" class="type_selected ticket_type_common" title="34">33</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

My requirement is on clicking a particular cell, I want the value and the class of the div tag.

```
        $("#layout").delegate('tr td','click',function(){
            var seat_selected=$(this).text();
            seat_selected=$(this).html();
            }
        });
```

Using $(this).text gives me the number 33.
Using $(this).html() gives the entire section inside td(I get the entire div).
But I want only the class of the div tag.
What is the procedure to get the class names of the div tag to a variable.

My requirement is to check for a particular class in the div tag and change the div tag to another class.
For example if the cell that I clicked had div tag with class (type_normal type_common) , I want  to change the class of the div tag to (type_selected type_common)

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can get class name by the following method,

```
var classOfDiv = $(this).find('div').attr('class');
```

Your code would be

```
$("#layout").delegate('tr td', 'click', function() {
        var seat_selected = $(this).text();
        seat_selected = $(this).html();
        var classOfDiv = $(this).find('div').attr('class'); 
        if($(this).find('div').attr('class') == "type_normal type_common")
            $(this).find('div').attr('class', 'type_selected type_common')
});
```

Comment: The selector is `tr td` so `this` will be the `<td />` and not the `<div />`

Comment: I got "undefined" . Also I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: @PSathiya updated my answer try it and tell if it does not work.

Comment: @PSathiya Your edit completely changes the question. If you're going to ask how to do something, you really should make sure the question is what you want the first time around rather than changing it after people have spent time answering it.

Comment: Thank you @Adil and @Andreas for the quick reply.I got the solution.               `$("#seat_layout").delegate('tr td div','click',function(){
                var seat_selected=$(this).text();
                seat_selected=$(this).attr('class');
                $(this).removeClass('ticket_type_normal');
                $(this).addClass('ticket_type_selected');
            });
        }`

Comment: Forgive me @Anthony, I will draft my questions carefully going forward

Comment: No worries @Anthony, I have updated my answer to what I understand from you changed question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('div').attr('class')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your callback function for the `click` event handler, `this` refers to the `<td>` element. You can then use the `.find()` jQuery function to select elements inside of that element that match a given selector. In your case, that would look like this:

```
var $tdDiv = $(this).find('div');
```

That gives you a jQuery object that contains the `<div>` element inside your `<td>`, then you can use the `className` property to get its current classes:

```
var divClass = $tdDiv.prop('className');
```

Then you can use the `.text()` function to get its "value":

```
var divValue = $tdDiv.text();
```

EDIT:
Based on additional information added to the question, in particular this part:

> My requirement is to check for a particular class in the div tag and change the div tag to another class. For example if the cell that I clicked had div tag with class (type_normal type_common) , I want to change the class of the div tag to (type_selected type_common)

You can use the `.hasClass()` function to check if the element(s) in the jQuery object have a particular class, the `addClass()` function to add a class and the `removeClass()` function to remove a class (or use `toggleClass()` to add or remove, depending on whether the class is already on the element).

```
var $tdDiv = $(this).find('div.type_common.type_normal')
$tdDiv.removeClass('type_normal').addClass('type_selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#layout").on('click', 'tr td', function() {
    var seat_selected = $(this).children(":first").attr('class')
    alert(seat_selected)
});
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/mqLfd/